# HTML/CSS Submenu not visible

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I am making a page where there should be a sub menu. In my page, i divided it into 3 category (header, content, footer). and I always insert the menu and sub menu in the header, I first tested it out in a test.html file, however, when i applied it in my main page, the content seems to be overlapping the sub menu.

do you guys have any idea on how i could fix this?

this is the usual template i used(without the sub menu, its working fine)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Sample website</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!--internal style -->
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <header id="header">
        <div id="menu" class="menu">
            <ul class="menu2">
                <li class="child"><a href="index.php" > HOME </a> </li>
                <li><a href="#"> ABOUT THE PRODUCT </a>
                <ul class="sub"> 
                    <li> <a href="#" > PRODUCT </a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="#" > PRODUCT REVIEWS </a> </li>
                </ul>
                </li>
                <li> <a href="#" > BLOG </a>
                <ul>
                    <li> <a href="#" > ARTICLES </a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="#" > RECIPES </a> </li>
                </ul>
                </li>
                <li> <a href="#" > ABOUT US </a> </li>
                <li> <a href="#" > CONTACT US </a> </li>
            </ul> 
        </div>
</header>


<section id="content">
    <h2>Welcome visitor!</h2>
    <div id="news">
    <center>
        <p> insert text here </p>
    </center>   
    </div>  
</section>


<footer id="footer">
    <div id="fmenu" class="fmenu">
        <p>©2015 ALL RIGHTS RESERVED</p>
</footer>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

here is a screenshot

[image]

i think its the css for my other things, so il change it. see here, im not using everything in the css, its just the template i usually do

```
html, body, div, span, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
abbr, address, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, samp,
small, strong, sub, sup, var,
b, i,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    outline:0;
    font-size:100%;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    background:transparent;
}

body {
    line-height:1;
}

article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,
footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section { 
    display:block;
}

nav ul {
    list-style:none;
}

blockquote, q {
    quotes:none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content:'';
    content:none;
}

a {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-size:100%;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    background:transparent;
}

/* change colours to suit your needs */
ins {
    background-color:#ff9;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
}

/* change colours to suit your needs */
mark {
    background-color:#ff9;
    color:#000; 
    font-style:italic;
    font-weight:bold;
}

del {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

abbr[title], dfn[title] {
    border-bottom:1px dotted;
    cursor:help;
}

table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: -25px;
}

/* change border colour to suit your needs */
hr {
    display:block;
    height:1px;
    border:0;   
    border-top:1px solid #cccccc;
    margin:1em 0;
    padding:0;
}

input, select {
    vertical-align:middle;
}

/* css starts here*/
body {
    background: url(images/background.jpg);
    font-family: Verdana !important;
    font-size: 10pt;
    line-height: 20px;

}
#header {
    background: url(images/smoothteamLOGO2.jpg) no-repeat;
    min-height: 270px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-size: 100%;
}
#content {
    background: #fff;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

#container {
    width: 826px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px #ccc;
}
/* added codes*/
#menu {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#menu ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 245px;
    line-height:30px;
    margin-left:35px;
}

#menu li{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}
#menu ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
#menu ul li a {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 1px 14px 0;
    margin: 0px;
    color: #fff;

    text-align:center;
    font-family:"Comic Sans MS", cursive;
    text-decoration:none;
    height:30px;
    width:120px;
    display:block;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #000;
    padding-bottom:25px;

}

#menu ul ul{
    position:absolute;
    visibility:hidden;
    top:32px;

}

#menu ul li:hover ul{
    visibility:visible;

}

/*******************************/
#menu li:hover{
    opacity: 0.6;
    filter: alpha(opacity=60);
}

#menu ul li:hover ul li a:hover{
    background:#ccc;
    color:#000;

}

#menu a:hover{
    color:#000;
}

.clearFloat{
    clear:both;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;

}

ul.menu
{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-top: -47px;
    margin-left: -35px;
    font-size: 13px;
}
li.menu
{
    display: inline-block;

}
a:link,a:visited
{
    text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover,a:active
{
    text-decoration: underline;
}

h2 {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-top: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 28px;
    color: #000;
    margin: 10px 10px;
    padding: 13px 10px;
}

#content p {
    margin: 30px 30px;
}

#footer {
    background: url(images/background2.jpg);
    min-height: 25px;
    background-size: 100%;
    clear: both;
}
#fmenu ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 120px;
    padding-top: 19px;
}
#fmenu ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
#fmenu ul li a {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 1px 14px 0;
    margin-top: 0px;
    color: #000000;
}

ul.fmenu
{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-top: -47px;
    margin-left: -35px;
    font-size: 13px;
}
li.fmenu
{
    display: inline-block;
    color:: black;


}

#footer p {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 209px;
    display: inline;
    width: 850px;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #fff;
}

#signup form{
    width: 400px;
}

#signup form ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: 20px;

}

#signup ul li{
    margin: 15px, 0;
}

#signup form label{
    display: block;

}

#signup form input, textarea, select{

    padding: 5px;
    border: #ccc 3px solid;
    width: 100%;
}

#news ul li{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well in my question above, after searching so many forums, this one worked on me. I already knew it was the content that was blocking my drop down, coz when i move the ul up, you could see the text, i made a few adjustments as well. then when my drop down appeared, i was unable to click the sub menu that hits the content part. in a forum(that talks about opacity, another problem I'm encountering now), it says when there are 2 divs, it would affect everything, correct me if i wrong xD thats what i have read, so ok, they he said add this on that content page, so i added this line of code

```
position:relative;
```

and yes it worked :)

this is the what happens earlier, then add position: relative on #content to see the fix

https://jsbin.com/zulese/1/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 1):

Just add `overflow: hidden` to here:

```css
#menu {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

**Bin: http://jsbin.com/mezilowiva/edit?css,output**

Comment: i tried this but it still doesnt let me view it, il try to post an image to make my question clear

Comment: @MisaChan Have a look at the bin, it works. It is a live working example. Are you able to see it?

Comment: thats weird mind shows up like this, is there a way i can post an image for you to see?

Comment: i added it on the question. i just added what you have said, but still, i can't view the sub menu. i think the content is blocking it

Comment: i tried the bin, its not showing the dropdown as well

Comment: please check this, i do think its working, however i did notice this, once the dropdown hits the content part? its not click able, like there is a wall blocking it. https://jsbin.com/zulese/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: done xD i added this below the #content in css position:relative; can i answer my question as well so that others may see it?

Answer (score 0):

overflow:hidden on your css should fix it. This way it won't go over what you have defined.

Comment: How is this different from my answer?

Comment: overflow: hidden will only continue not showing what i needed, i tested it out on bin and it ain't working! i removed it and its working fine